# How can I check if an element is a drop down list element or a text input element, given its id?

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, given the `id` of an element (in a `String` format), how can I check if the `id` of the element refers to a drop down list element, or a text input element?

The function should return `true` if the `id` refers to a drop down list (`<select>`) element, or a text input element, and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try using:
`document.getElementById('idNameGoesHere').tagName`

So the function could be:

```
function isSelectOrTextField(idName) {
    var element = document.getElementById(idName);
    if(element.tagName === 'SELECT') {return true;}
    if(element.tagName === 'INPUT' && element.type === 'text') {return true;}
    return false;
}
```

You could expand this to check for `<textarea>` as well.

**EDIT :**
Or choose jbabey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416455/206614) as it's using `nodeName` and is better formatted.

apparently [`nodeName` has wider browser support.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t23)

Comment: The advantage of this one is that it's not using jquery.

Answer (score 32):

If you already have jquery included, you can use [the is function](http://api.jquery.com/is/) :

```
$('#myid').is('input, select')
```

or maybe

```
$('#myid').is('input, textarea, select')
```

if you want to also include textarea

or

```
$('#myid').is('input:not([type="button"]), textarea, select')
```

(this one returns true if it's a textare or a dropdown or an input that is not a button).

You have the whole power of [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to adapt your query to your exact needs.

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/ELuEJ/ (try to change the html)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `nodeName` and `type` properties of the DOM elements to determine this. No external libraries are required.

```
var isSelectOrTextInput = function (element) {
    var nodeName = element.nodeName;

    return nodeName === 'SELECT' || 
        (nodeName === 'INPUT' && 
         element.type.toLowerCase() === 'text');
};
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ytHQD/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myId')[0].tagName
```

you can retrive the dom element and then check the tagName